# Is there a relationship between the faction quests and main quest?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

As I'm playing a game, I like to finish all the side quests in one region before I move to the next for the main quest. Unfortunately, this is slightly problematic in KoA. I started the main quest and faction quests in Dalentarth, then the main quest wanted me to move on to Detyre while the next part of the faction quest lines wanted me to go to the Plains of Erathell. So it looks like this, very back and forth:

[image]

It's starting to get a bit confusing because I find myself region hopping a lot. So I have a few questions:

Is there a certain order in which I should complete quests?

Is there a convenient way to complete tasks between these quest lines (instead of just region hopping between faction and main quests)?

Do the faction and main quest lines ever coexist in the same region again?

Comment: As someone who usually likes to go through questing in a similar fashion as you, at this point I'm thinking I may have to end up going back and doing side quests by entire geographic regions such as all "Faelands" quests before moving to the next region.  I am not far along enough yet to know if that will even work well, so I'll be interested to see what other people who are further along have to say.

Comment: @kazzamalla you might be able to do it with side quests but the faction quests are inter-regional. That's what's really stumping me...I have no idea which I should pursue first. Generally, I do my faction quests *alongside* my main quest

Comment: @spugsley, my strategy so far as just been do "do whatever's closest" - I'll take all the quests from a region, and then do the next closest thing on my map.  This way, I stay in the same region longer and can fight roughly the same level enemies, while taking advantage of the fact that they don't respawn immediately after I kill them.

Comment: @agent86 that's what I find myself doing but I'm hoping there's someone out there who's found a better way. I don't mind this strategy with side quests. With faction quests, however, I prefer to kind of go one right after the other when I start them in order to have some continuity. I'm getting used to it, but I'm still curious if there's a good way to go about things. Perhaps some order or something so that everything fits together nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There actually are different quest lines that somewhat follow others (I haven't played in a few months so I can't remember exactly which ones follow which). I did the main quest line and once I was supposed to switch regions (Faelands to Detyre, for example), I did the factions quest lines up until it wanted me to go to another area.

So just do the quests in the region you are in, and once you have to switch, you have all the quests you want in that area versus having to travel all around the map to finish one then move on to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the plains of erathell before detyre (in the main quest), so yes, they can work together :).